# git, trying to pull a specific commit from remote, not the most recent one

Tags: git

How can I pull a specific commit, or rather pull the repo the way it was after a specific commit? I don't have any branches. I'm just running master, and I am the only one using this repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pull an then checkout the commit you want to see:

```
git pull && git co <commit>
```

or you can pull and then reset HEAD to a different commit:

```
git pull && git reset --hard <commit>
```

I do not think there is a way to pull only a specific commit since it is easy it git to switch to another commit if needed.

Comment: `git fetch && git reset --hard <commit>` avoids merging altogether.

Comment: Or create a new local branch to work with for that commit, `git checkout -b test <commit>` delete it with `git branch -d test` when done with it

Comment: thanks, I used the first one git pull && git co <commit> and it does exactly what I wanted.